# Are "what language...?" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions, scope

The phrase "what language" in a title tends to be followed by one of:

1. "is this?" (code snippet)
2. "should I use for X?"
3. "is X programmed in?"

See ["what language"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+title%3A%22what+language%22), ["what languages"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+title%3A%22what+languages%22)

I'd argue that

- (1) does not demonstrate minimal understanding, or even a problem
- (2) is opinion-based
- (3) is a weird combination: does not demonstrate a specific problem in an off-site resource

But, before I flag most of the ~400 (eventually), are these questions on-topic?

Comment: I suggest changing your search to ["what language is"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+title%3A%22what+language+is%22) rather than "what language". There are far fewer results (71 vs 300~) and it's probably closer to the type of question you refer to here.

Comment: Low effort, lack of minimal understanding or primary opinion based.

Comment: @JonW I just did some searching, and to account for only "what language is/does/should/to" doesn't capture nearly all of the possible ways to ask those questions. Which is your point, I know, but restricting the search by adding a verb reduces the possible benefit of such a search.

Comment: Well point 2 of your list is certainly off-topic, but points 1 and 3 are slightly different questions so I wouldn't group all those posts under the same search. By splitting the search out you'll be able to deal with both type of questions separately - close off any *'what language should I...'* questions but (depending on what people on this question say) perhaps deal with the *'what language is...'* questions differently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that [programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language) is a *tool* to get particular job done, questions asking to recommend a language match the canned close reason:

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a tool**, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam...
>
> [image]

Comment: +1 for a Freehand Red Circle!

Answer (score 2):

These are three completely different categories of questions.

#### What language is this code snippet written in?

Meh. I have a hard time seeing how these questions can be useful, and this is coming from a staunch defender of story identification questions on literature-type sites. They're extremely rare on SO. What is it, 10 questions out of a couple of millions? Why are we wasting time on this?

#### What language should I use?

Primarily opinion-based unless there's some very very strong constraint.

#### What language is X programmed in?

Off-topic — it's about X, not about programming.